# Cygwin/X windows opening with titlebar off the top of the screen

Tags: cygwin, x11

I am using Cygwin/X with a ssh tunnel to a remote server.  If I launch a window from that remote server without explicitly setting the geometry, it appears in the top-left corner of the screen, with the titlebar completely off the top of the screen.
This makes it a pain to drag around, because I have to use the "shift-rightclick taskbar item, 'move', arrow keys" trick to to move it to where I can see the titlebar to properly drag the window.

**Is there any way to configure cygwin/x to default new window locations to a better place, or to at least place them entirely on the screen?**  It seems like now when it is placing it, it is ignoring the Windows "decorations" and just placing the first internal pixel at 0,0.  I can't explicitly set the -geometry flag for everything I launch, as some windows are launched within other applications.

I'm using Windows 7, the latest Cygwin/X, and -multiwindow mode with two monitors.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Any change you found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my problem was due to the arrangement of my dual monitors.

My secondary monitor was taller than my primary, so my "virtual" window was the max height of the two.  I adjusted the placement of the desktops to be aligned on the top of the monitors instead of the bottom, and now my windows open in the correct place.

Comment: Sadly that seems like a horrible kludge to work around this :(